# opening Python IDLE with AutoHotKey

Tags: python, autohotkey, python-idle

I've been messing around with AutoHotKey, trying to create some useful shortcuts for myself. I can open file explorer, calculator, chrome, etc., but I haven't been able to write a program that opens Python IDLE.

My program says:

```
!t::
Run pythonw
return
```

I've tried pythonw.exe, python.exe, python, python3.exe, and a bunch of other combinations. Any idea why it isn't working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, your problem is that Python IDLE is different from  pythonw.exe, python.exe, python, python3.exe .

Python IDLE is an IDE or Code Editor provided with python whereas pythonw.exe, python.exe, python, python3.exe  are the python interpreter.

pythonw.exe - for executing python scripts without opening console window(Hidden)
python OR python3.exe OR python3.exe - are the same, that is the normal python interpreter.

So to open IDLE you should execute the IDLE file not the interpreter.

The path for IDLE(in Windows Computer) is usually :

```
C:\Python39\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat
```

Here the Python version is 3.9 but it may be different in your case!
Check for the version you installed by opening command prompt and typing :

```
C:\>python --version
Python 3.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Turning the info that Jaysmito provided into an AutoHotkey Script:

```
!t::
Run C:\Python39\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat
return
```

However, the `Python39` part of the directory above will vary based on which version of python you have installed. To check which version of Python you are using, use the `python --version` command in a command prompt window. Then if your version of Python is not in the `3.9.*` range, change the directory above to match your version.

For example, if your version is in the `2.7.*` range, your directory would be something like `Run C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat`, with the `Python39` from above changed to `Python27`.

Answer (score 0):

`idle.bat` is Windows specific, and there are Windows-specific reasons for its existence.  The generic way to start IDLE in its default startup mode (partly user customizable) is `somepython -m idlelib` where `somepython` refers to and start a python binary.  It can be `python`, `pythonw` (Windows), `python3` (*nix), or `py -3.y` (Windows).  For 2.x, use `idlelib.idle` instead of `idlelib`.